# Create a Multipart Request from multiple HTTP responses

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I have to create a multipart/form-data HTTP request where the file will be received from one request, some additional form data values from different requests. Example:

1) HTTP listener receives the file as attachment 

2) Sends HTTP requests to 3 or more REST APIs, and stores values into property variables

3) Create a HTTP request with the file received in step 1 along with values received in step 2

When I receive the file in step 1 I save it in a property, I also save values from subsequent requests into different properties.

Now When I construct a HTTP POST request from these properties in Step 3 I don't receive any values on the server, neither the fields nor the file.

My Flow:

```html
<http:request-config name="HTTP_poster_Configuration" host="localhost" port="53536"  doc:name="HTTP Poster Configuration"/>
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="1.1.1.1"  basePath="/xyz" port="8080"  doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
    <http:listener-config  name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
   
   
    <flow name="getticketFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>


        

        <set-session-variable variableName="var1" value="NA" doc:name="Session Variable" />
       
         <set-variable variableName="var2" value="P11335577" doc:name="Flow name Variable" />
          <set-variable variableName="var3" value="Goku" doc:name="Flow title Variable" />
           <set-variable variableName="var4" value="Saiyan Dead but Alive" doc:name="Flow description Variable" />
           
  <set-variable variableName="uploadFile" value="#[message.inboundAttachments['file'].dataSource.content]" doc:name="Flow type Variable" /> 
             
.................Sending requests to other services
...................Setting property Variables    

<!--    Finally -->
  <http:request  config-ref="HTTP_poster_Configuration"  path="/handler" method="POST" doc:name="Uploading_Doc"  > 
             <http:request-builder>
                <http:query-param paramName="filedata" value="#[flowVars ['uploadFile']]"/>
            
                <http:query-param paramName="sid" value="#[flowVars ['var1']]"/>
                <http:query-param paramName="cid" value="#[flowVars ['var2']]"/>
                <http:query-param paramName="udi" value="#[flowVars ['var3']]"/>

                <http:header headerName="Content-Type" value="multipart/form-data"/>
             </http:request-builder>
           
        
         </http:request>
 
         
       
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to send the file and the other data in a multipart request then you need to add everything as attachments, not query params as in your flow right now. Each attachment will then translate to a "part" in the request.
So before the final `request` you need to use the `set-attachment` component.
You can find more on this [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/http-request-connector#sending-multipart-requests).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, now the file name is same as the key name of the attachment. How can I set the file name of the attachment.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I see you saved the file content-type and then used that for the attachment. Did that solve the filename issue?

Comment: No it did not. so I decided to send the file name separately in the request to the listener as well. If I try #[message.inboundAttachments['filedata'].dataSource.getName()] it just returns the Key Name i.e. 'filedata'. Any other suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: I don't understand why am I unable to extract the file name from the inbound attachment nor am I able to set the file name of the outbound attachment. The outbound attachment takes the 'attachmentName' as the filename. At the receiving side the server looks for the key 'filedatax' to retrieve the file attachment, hence the attachment name and key name have to be different in this case.

Comment: What happens if you store the whole "file" instead of the content? There were some issues around attachments that were fixed. You could be affected by https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8800. Which mule version are you using?

Comment: If I store the whole file using  it throws 'javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException' pertaining to MIME type not being supported. I am using Mule Server 3.7.3 EE .

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did as per afelisatti's suggestion it works now:

```html
<set-variable variableName="uploadAttachmentCT" value="#[message.inboundAttachments['filedata'].dataSource.getHeader('Content-Type')]" doc:name="Attachment Content Type" />

<set-variable variableName="uploadFile" value="#[message.inboundAttachments['filedata'].dataSource.content]" doc:name="File to be Uploaded" /> 

 <set-attachment attachmentName="filedatax" value="#[flowVars ['uploadFile']]"  contentType="#[flowVars['uploadAttachmentCT']]" />
        <set-attachment attachmentName="site" value="#[flowVars['uploadSite']]" contentType="text/plain" />
 <set-attachment attachmentName="filename" value="#[flowVars['filename']]" contentType="text/plain" />
                <set-payload doc:name="Set payload as null" value="#[null]"/>
        
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/xyz" method="POST" doc:name="Uploading_Doc"/>
```

Comment: If an answer worked for you, mark it as the correct answer, or at least vote up.